# packet drop in usb interface after establishment of ppp on it

Tags: usbserial

USB interface is getting created and also ppp is established . After sending few packets perfectly the packets are getting dropped.thats why ppp interface is down and never getup.
This scenario is ocurring everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I got reason behind it. Actually Due to USB HUB device ,it was difficult to read the data on read register of Host controller.USB HUB was having long wire.So i just used short wired HUB.